# Cordova: Position:sticky invalid property value

Tags: css, cordova

On https://myroutes.io/routes the #stickybar and .navbar are stickied to the top of the page. But this exact same page on cordova is marked as an invalid property.

What is a good workaround? The .navbar is stickied at top: 0px; and the #stickyBar at top: 60px;

```
#stickyBar {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: -moz-sticky;
  position: -ms-sticky;
  position: -o-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  margin-top: 0px;
  top: 60px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

[image]

Comment: On which device are you testing?

Comment: @Beat OnePlus 2. Crosswalk is included

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm seeing a similar behavior with position:sticky

Answer (score 0):

Make same #stickybar again and move both position to there

Comment: Could you elaborate maybe with a short code snippet?